# EDI Sample data for transaction sets

Tags: edi

I am building an EDI 850 integration and now want to test the functionality/accuracy of my mappings using dummy EDI transactions. Does anyone know how to generate sample 004010 850s? Or where I could find a variety of diverse valid 000410 850s (e.g. with different segment combinations or with different element codes)?

Where do people go to get sample EDI transactions in general (once I build this for other transactions as well)?

Comment: Your trading partner should be sending you sample files.  Otherwise you can get sample files off the internet and edit to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a valid X12 850, go to https://edi.stedi.com/inspector?value=&view=undefined and click `Try a sample` it loads an 004010 850 that you can play with.

And any Mapping Guide will have sample EDI transactions in the bottom section. You can paste this into the inspector tool and get back any validation errors. Sometimes the trading partner gives invalid EDI examples lol.

Who is the trading partner, their mapping guides might already exist in https://edi.stedi.com/mapping-guides